# MySQL's TIME() function in h2 with Java

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, h2

So, I need to translate the following query into Java

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE TIME(date) BETWEEN TIME(startTime) AND TIME(endTime)
```

where `date` is a datetime column. Both `startTime` and `endTime` are local variables.

The technologies that I'm using right now are Spring and Hibernate.

The following solution

```
query.add(
         Restrictions.sqlRestriction(
             "TIME(date) between TIME('?') and TIME('?')", values, types
     );
```

, where the `values` variable is an array with `startTime` and `endTime` and the `types` variable is an array with the `values`'s respective types (string), unfortunately is not compatible with H2, since the `TIME` function wasn't implemented. I do know that the `HOUR`, `MINUTE` and `SECOND` functions are implemented and working.

I haven't figured out a way of implementing it myself and couldn't find any solution online. Does anyone have any idea of how I can overcome this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read through the HQL language specification, you will find that it is largely devoid of any support for date/time functions.  This is mainly due to that every database has its own way of handling date and time, so there is little common support.  However, the `CAST` function is supported by HQL, assuming the underlying database also supports it.  From the [H2 documentation](http://www.h2database.com/html/functions.html#cast), we find this example of casting to time:

```
CAST(TIMESTAMP '2010-01-01 10:40:00.123456' AS TIME(6))
```

So, you may try doing this in your HQL query:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE
    CAST(date AS TIME(6)) BETWEEN CAST(startTime AS TIME(6)) AND
                                  CAST(endTime AS TIME(6));
```